# Is it possible to upload an album from Picasa to Google Photos without creating duplicates?

Tags: google-photos

Suppose I have 100 photos in Google Photos and that I also have those same 100 photos locally on my computer (synced via Google Drive).

If I (locally) use Picasa to create an album containing, say, 25 of those photos, is there any way for me to upload that album to a Google Photos collection such that it does not create 25 duplicate photos?  My experience and testing is that when I upload the album, duplicates are created.